# How to select different columns from database each giving the sum(or similar) of another query result?

Tags: php, mysql

Here is sample query

```
SELECT 
    name, 
    sum(SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE cond='1' and cond2='2') as mysum1, 
    sum(SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE cond3='3' and cond4='4') as mysql2 
FROM 
    mytable 
WHERE 
    userid='1' and status='1';
```

Obviously this does not work but I think you can now understand what I mean. How to retrieve records in this manner.

Comment: Why do you want to get a sum of ids? Maybe you want to get a count instead?

Comment: @naktibaldo, this is just an example, I am going to use this concept to export a marksheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to calculate sums inside subqueries:

```
SELECT 
    name, 
    (SELECT sum(numbers) FROM mytable WHERE cond='1' and cond2='2') as mysum1, 
    (SELECT sum(numbers) FROM mytable WHERE cond3='3' and cond4='4') as mysym2
FROM 
    mytable 
WHERE 
    userid='1' and status='1';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT 
    name, 
    (SELECT SUM(id) FROM mytable WHERE cond='1' and cond2='2') as mysum1, 
    (SELECT SUM(id) FROM mytable WHERE cond3='3' and cond4='4') as mysql2 
FROM 
    mytable 
WHERE 
    userid='1' and status='1';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a count of rows matching these conditions, use this query:

```
SELECT 
    name, 
    SUM(cond='1' AND cond2='2') AS mysum1,
    SUM(cond3='3' AND cond4='4') AS mysum2
FROM mytable 
WHERE 
    userid='1' AND 
    status='1';
```